# Build fail in msbuild source code(https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild)

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have cloned MSBuild source code from (https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild) and followed below steps to build the project.

Building MSBuild with Visual Studio 2017

- Install Visual Studio 2017.
- Clone the source code
- Build the code using the cibuild.cmd script
- Open src/MSBuild.sln solution and build in Visual Studio 2017

But build is getting failed with following errors when we try to build from VS 2017

The imported project "C:\msbuildgit\msbuild\packages\Nerdbank.GitVersioning\1.5.46\build\dotnet\Nerdbank.GitVersioning.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.UnitTests

The imported project "C:\msbuildgit\msbuild\packages\Nerdbank.GitVersioning\1.5.46\build\dotnet\Nerdbank.GitVersioning.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. Microsoft.Build.Engine.OM.UnitTests

and also following projects are not getting loaded

Microsoft.Build ,Microsoft.Build.Framework,Microsoft.Build.Tasks
Microsoft.Build.Utilities,MSBuildTaskHost

getting following error , when we try to reload above projects

C:\msbuildgit\msbuild\src\Build\Microsoft.Build.csproj : error : The imported project "C:\msbuildgit\msbuild\packages\Nerdbank.GitVersioning\1.5.46\build\dotnet\Nerdbank.GitVersioning.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. C:\msbuildgit\msbuild\src\dir.targets

following options have been tried  and both were getting failed

- tried restoring nuget packages
- tried installing Nerdbank.GitVersioning nuget(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nerdbank.GitVersioning/)

Please note that cibuild.cmd script has been already executed

Please help us on this.

Comment: suggest creating an issue in msbuild repo

Comment: When creating a build-server, I run into missing .targets files on occasion.  Sadly, the only thing I've figured out is to actually find the targets file and put it manually on the build-server at that location.  Now, usually that target file is sitting in a developer box with visual studio installed (the build server uses msbuild.exe and does NOT have vs installed).  So while it stinks, I'd suggest trying to find the targets file and put them right where the error says it ought to be as a short term solution.  Then post an issue at the site where you got the code/instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolve by following below steps ,Jeff Kluge helped on this after raising this issue in GitHub(https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1947)

- Open Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017
- Run cd /d C:\msbuildgit\msbuild
- Run git clean -xfd to clean the enlistment
- Run cibuild.cmd --build-only to build the source code